# How to import a class using javaagent

Tags: java, javaagents

I am trying to import the Serializable interface into a java executable using javaagent. How is this possible?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Do you want to create your own javaagent?  What do you mean by "java executable"?

Comment: I have a jar file that I want to execute. I do not have its source. I want to write a javaagent that adds a statement to each method to check if its parameters are Serializable. But for that, I need to be able to import Serializable into the jar file from the javaagent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it. In the `transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class clazz, java.security.ProtectionDomain domain, byte[] bytes)` method, just add `loader.loadClass("java.io.Serializable")`.